# iOS Navigation Breadcrumb Trail

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Basically, I have a client that wants a breadcrumb trail implemented in the navigation bar. I realize Apple doesn't recommend this behavior, but the app I'm building is for internal use only and won't be submitted to the App Store.

I need something along the lines of what AirVideo uses in their iPad App. Are there any navigation controllers that provide this functionality or any other code available?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to create your own custom View Controller that holds a reference to the other views, and draws the buttons how you want.

Comment: Yeah obviously, but I was hoping someone had implemented something similar or there was existing code somewhere. I have an idea of how to implement it, but if there's already a solution that would be ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure of any examples or frameworks that do this, but perhaps a more specific question would draw more attention. Maybe something like "are there any iOS breadcrumb navigation controllers?" rather than "Any ideas?" which might be a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

I have done similar, but unfortunately I cannot share any code, as it is bound by NDA. But I can guide you for an easy solution.

- Use UIWebView for breadcrumb.
- Use CSS to show your items (like http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/breadcrumb/#) which are enumerated from UIViewController stack
- Give links, custom schema linkes, like (controller://1, controller://2 etc)
- handle UIWebView requests, and use popToViewController of UINavigationController to change to selected controller

that's it

hope this helps