# iPad breadcrumb control?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am looking for a breadcrumb style navigation controller for iPad.  Specifically I would like to know if the control in this picture actually exists or is made with custom images:

http://iconlibrary.iconshock.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/ipad-vector-buttons-GUI.jpg

The control I'm talking about is towards the top of the image with the home icon followed closely by buttons with the text "label".  The closest thing I can think of is a UISegmentedControl, but that doesn't have the borders that point backwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Navigation Breadcrumb Trail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035715/ios-navigation-breadcrumb-trail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no UIKit framework for that particular behavior, and I'm not aware of any open source software that would do so.

Depends on how exactly you'd like to implement it, but you could use a UINavigationController with a custom toolbar at the top.